# What kind of exception to manually throw from an Axis web service?

Tags: java, exception, jax-ws

I have some webservices that are developed on axis 1.1, and I need to make a few changes.  During this I am fixing up the exception handling code, but I don't know what kind of exception I should throw when there is an error.

I only need to send the message to the client, I don't need to worry about stack traces and custom information in the exceptions.  I don't want to deal with extending soapfaults, or providing reasons for the failures, and all that jazz.

```
@WebMethod
public string[] myMethod() throws ..?.. {
    throw new AxisFault(); // not recommended
    throw new SOAPFaultException();  // seems overly general
    throw new Exception(); // what we have now
}
```

Is there any right way to do this, or is `throw new Exception` the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a custom exception (say `FooException`) extending `Exception` annotated with JAX-WS [`@WebFault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/WebFault.html).

```
@WebFault(faultBean = "org.foo.bar.FooFault")
public class FooException extends Exception {
    private FooFault fooFault;

    public FooException() {
        super();
    }

    public FooException(String message, FooFault fooFault, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.fooFault = fooFault;
    }

    public FooException(String message, FooFault fooFault) {
        super(message);
        this.fooFault = fooFault;
    }

    public FooFault getFaultInfo() {
        return fooFault;
    }
}

// this is org.foo.bar.FooFault
public class FooFault {
    // POJO
}
```

And then you declare that your web method throws that exception.

```
@WebMethod
public string[] myMethod() throws FooException {
    // do some stuff
    throw new FooException();
    // or with a cause
    try { 
        // something dangerous
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FooException("Shit happens", new FooFault(), e);
    }
    // or like this
    throw new FooException("Foo", new FooFault());
}
```

JAX-WS should do the rest.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just throwing a standard exception?  Since we derive from exception here, I assume there isn't an issue.  If not, then I will just stick to that for the moment until something requires more information.  That is quite a nice little example, though, which I will come back to if we need more.  Thanks :)

Comment: For me there is nothing really wrong with that, but the generated SOAP-Fault may not contains any useful information. The above mechanism does because JAX-WS will call the `getFaultInfo()` in order to tell what went wrong and include it in the `detail` tag of soap fault.

Comment: Hm... I'll have to look into that.  I dont know much about this.  At this point all I want to do is send the exception & message back, no details needed (they are all logged on the server with a UID which is returned in the message, etc.)   I'll have to try to tigger an exception and see what data I get back now.